# How to I get rid of my helicopter on GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My friend was rifling through my Xbox on GTA V and bought the Pegasus Volatus Helicopter which I only just noticed. I don't know what to do because I was suddenly missing 3 million.

What do I do? I play on Xbox One.

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to tell you that there is no way of refunding in-game money. [Here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204247107-24-Hour-Refund-Period-on-GTA-Online-In-Game-Purchases-) is a link to someone wanting to refund himself, yet to no avail (Rockstar Forums)

PS.: People seem to be rather rude when asking for this on the official forum, so I'd advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Crowley Astray](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/312890/130645) points out, it's not possible to refund money spent in game.

Unfortunately, you [can't even *sell* Pegasus vehicles](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pegasus+vehicle+refund&oq=pegasus+vehicle+refund&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3543j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=pegasus+vehicle+sell), so you can't even make back some of your money.